# Create extension into a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, postgis

I want to do `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` in a migration but i also want to check (in this migration) if the user has installed PostGIS or not (if not, abort the migration).

Is it possible to do so ?

My code is

```
   class CreateExtensionPostgis < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        execute <<-SQL
              CREATE extension IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
            SQL
      end
    end
```

Comment: The code should work, i have a user rights problem (must be superuser to execute the command) but it should work. The problem is, it doesn't check if the user (because there's multiple users) has installed PostGIS or not. What it does is creating the extension for the database given **the extension** doesn't already exists

Comment: So you want create an extension without the superuser permission? Or What?

Comment: I already have superuser permission (didn't have it the first time i ran the migration), the problem is checking if the user has PostGIS installed on his computer or not, can i do that in a migration ?

Comment: You can query available extensions by [`pg_available_extensions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html)

Comment: Interesting, so having postgis as an available extension means that postgis is installed (at least i think). Is it possible to do something like : `SELECT name FROM pg_available_extensions() WHERE name='postgis' IF EXISTS CREATE extension IF NOT EXISTS postgis;`